# Update textview in gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery, adapter

I am trying to update the textview in my gallery after it has been created using my updateCaption method, however, only the first textview in the gallery gets updated.  When I print out my textview, they all have the same ID like android.widget.TextView@40942d60.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private int[] image;
    private TextView caption;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        image = new int[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++)
        {
              image[i] = R.drawable.image;
        }
    }

    public void updateCaption(String text, int position)
    {
        System.out.println(position + ": text");
        caption.setText(text);

        System.out.println(caption);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return image.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView text, dssnum, scnum;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.caption, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            caption = holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.scnum = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.scnum);
            holder.dssnum = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.dss_num);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();


        holder.dssnum.setText("Unavailable");

        holder.image.setImageResource(image[position]);
        holder.text.setText("Not available.");
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Added: how I am using updateCaption

```
for (int j = 0; j < listOfList.get(i).size(); j++)
{
        galleryImageAdapter.updateCaption("test " + j, j);
 }
```

Comment: I don't even see where updateCaption is being called, am I just missing it or did you not post the code?

Comment: @Jack first method under constructor. Is the binder code available?

Comment: No I mean - I see where the method is defined, where is it called from? Like updateCaption("some text", 3);

Comment: I have my updateCaption being called in a for loop. Ill add it now

Comment: Also, why are you passing a position if you're not using it?

Comment: Earlier I had a ViewGroup[] vg and did this: caption = (TextView) vg[position].getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.textView1); however, that also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to this line...

```
caption = holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

once all convertView is created, your caption will always point to the textview of the last convertView.

Comment: I did not get your point to have updateCaption to change text. You should change the underlying data structure of adapter...and should call notifyDataSetChanged to update the view. Like how you are doing holder.text.setText("Not available.");....instead of this the Text Value should be set by some array or list of desired text. For ex : holder.text.setText(desiredText[position]);

Comment: But even if i did holder.text.setText(desiredText[position]), wouldnt I have to change what holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); is
?

Comment: No you do not, that's the whole point of doing this...lets take an example...you have array of Strings from 1 - 10. Initially you set your text view with 1 - 10 values. Now suppose you want to change 5th row value...what you will do you will change the 5th index of array...your view will be rendered with new value...because we are going by index of array = value of position in getView method. So you not need to worry about the view. Hope this help you in understand.